# Access Google Cloud Datastore from Node app running on local machine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Google Cloud Platform.

1. I have written a node application to add entities to the google cloud datastore.
2. I have a GCP(Google Cloud Platform) account and created a project within it to access the Google Cloud Datastore.
3. I have created service keys(JSON file) for the GCP project above and downloaded the former.

Now, i need to connect the node server running on my local machine to Google Cloud Datastore using the service account key. How can i do this? I got a bit confused with lot of documentations posted on Google cloud site. Can someone please explain me the steps/process/flow ?

Comment: Create a user in datastore and give access from your IP

Comment: @Bira Could you please explain in bit more detail? I dint quiet get that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Datastore has a local development server that you can use: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver

You can create and start the local datastore using the gcd tool which is linked to in the doc above.

If you use `DatastoreHelper.getDatastoreFromEnv();` to build your Datastore, you can tell it to connect to your local database by exporting the env variable DATASTORE_HOST:

```
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: I will try this and get back if i get more doubts. Thanks @Bira But i have a question. What is the purpose of Service account keys(JSON file)?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a remote google datastore from your local node app via the Google Service Key API:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#linux-or-macos

The process is simple enough:

1. Create a Google Service account key.
2. Export your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable to be the path where your key file is stored.

Mac/Linux (via command line)

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json"
```

Windows (via powershell)

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\my-key.json"
```

You can generate this Google Service Key by clicking this link:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey?_ga=fuckuranalytics